# Android: How to make a sum of all the results

Tags: java, android

Hello and thanks in advance for your help.  The idea is that the user put height and weight and it shows a result on a TextView. So when I run the app and lets say I put 2 and 2 the result is 8.  If I erase the previous values and put new ones the result comes out correctly.  My issue now is that I want to save every result and sum it, so the user would be able to press lets say the final_price_Button and get on the screen the sum of all the results. I apologize for any posting and coding mistakes still learning. Thanks again!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public double  calculation(double ypsos,double platos){
    double mypsos=ypsos;
    double mplatos=platos;

    double result=(mypsos*mplatos)*2;
    return result;
}
private EditText meditypsos;
private EditText meditplatos;
private Button mcalculate;
private double result;
private TextView mResultview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    meditypsos  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editypsos);
    meditplatos  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editplatos);
    mcalculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Calculate);
    mResultview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Resultview) ;

    mcalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           double num1=Double.parseDouble(meditypsos.getText().toString());
            double num2=Double.parseDouble(meditplatos.getText().toString());

        result=calculation(num1,num2);

            mResultview.setText(Double.toString(result));
        }

    });

}
}
```

Comment: Add your code to your question using a code block (four spaces) instead of linking to an external site. No one wants to open that link.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a List <> , Set <> or Map <>  (depending what you want do with yhis data) and display the items later .

Comment: it all depends how you will handle this data , do you will keep this data only at run time , and if onPause() or onDestroy() called this data need be kept or can be destroyed ?